# Comparing 2 distributions in R from a smaller sample

Tags: distributions, anova, biostatistics, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I am in the process of planning out a statistical analysis for future data I will collect. I am primarily a neurobiologist, trying to implement more appropriate statistical models for my data. First, we want to test the influence of a treatment, age, and a surgical procedure on the intensity of cells within a region. For this we will obtain intensity values from about 100-200 cells per subject, with each of our 12 groups having 8-10 subjects per.

In the literature, people combine these intensities within a group to end up with 1 distribution of cell intensities with thousands of cells as the individual data points for each group. I worry this is entirely inaccurate and ignoring the fact that this data came from 8-10 subjects, it also drastically increases your false detection rate.

Experimental Setup:
H(alternative): Influence of drug exposure depends on age and surgical status. We expect cell intensity to be reduced in some groups, and increased in others (from previous data), so this is two-tailed.
DV: Cell intensity (continuous scale but with a zero and an upper boundary)
IVs: Drug exposure (Y/N), age (young, adolescent, adult), and surgical status (Y/N)
Statistics Program: Rstudio

First I looked to the literature and the majority of people analyzing this type of data use simple ANOVA's but the real difference comes from what they assign as their sample size, assigning it as either the number of subjects or the much larger number of cells quantified from.

I've tried analyzing data where I averaged the intensity in each subject then averaged it for the group then ran a Two-Way ANOVA with the N set as the number of subjects (with a simpler experimental set up though only 2 IVs). I like this concept because it allows for us to be sure the effect isn't driven by a single subject, but I worry we are losing dimension with all of the averaging we need to do to get to this point. This also makes it so we don't have distributions, which I think could offer valuable resolution.

I've also tried combining these intensity values within a group, commonly seen in the literature, and then running two-sample KS tests comparing just two distributions at a time or running them through an ANOVA as if each is an independent observation. The issues I have with this are:

1. The true n of my group is not the thousands of cells I have data from...it is my 9-10 subjects. Personally I don't consider each cell assessed to be a true biological replicate, so this doesn't seem appropriate.
2. This method results in highly significant values for very low effect size findings.
3. This only allows you to compare two distributions at once (if you do KS rather than ANOVA), moving forward I need to compare at least 4 at a time...potentially even 12 at a time (still pondering whether age will be included in the model as I'm not particularly interested in how ages differ from one another, just how ages vary in the way they are effected).
4. Two-sample KS just tells you if two distributions are different, with no directionality.
5. There could be individual variation between members of a group that are missed, resulting in outliers driving the data set.

**So overall, I need a statistic that can be used to tell differences between distributions, but I also need to be able to correct for the fact that these thousand plus observations are from a smaller subset of subjects**. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated, even just a publication or type of statistic to run would do me wonders, my google searches keep populating information about correcting unequal sample sizes, which isn't really my issue here.